# Accessing scripts from inside a sub-folder in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, subdirectory

For a Unity project I am using this [ROSBridgeLib](https://github.com/MathiasCiarlo/ROSBridgeLib) from GitHub. There weren't any clear instructions for how to import the library, so I just cloned the repository into my `Scripts` folder inside my project's `Assets` folder. This causes Unity to throw an `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ROSBridgeLib' does not exist in the namespace 'ROSBridgeLib' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. How can I fix this issue?

I want to be able to organize my `Scripts` folder so I can keep C# files inside sub-folders. How can a script in the root of my `Scripts` folder access the `ROSBridgeLib` inside the folder `ROSBridgeLib` (which is a sub-folder of `Scripts`)?

**UPDATE:**

The initial problem has mysteriously stopped after I reset my Unity project, but now `ROSBridgeLib` and its components don't show up in my autocomplete in Visual Studios 2017.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Top of the readme links to a [working Unity project](https://github.com/michaeljenkin/unityros/tree/master/Assets). Have you tried looking at it?

Comment: Yeah, I tried mimicking that project's file tree, but it didn't work. I've copied `websocket-sharp.dll` into my Plugins folder and cloned the `ROSBridgeLib` folder into my `Assets` (and my `Scripts` folder on a second test). I am still experiencing the same problems.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a DLL, or possibly one of the code files, that contains the base libraries used by this code, is missing. Alas, I'm not familiar enough with ROSBridgeLib to tell you WHAT dll is missing.   Edit:  what is odd is that is specifies ROSBridgeLib as both, the namespace that doesn't exist, AND the namespace it's looking in (the second part indicates that it DOES in fact exist).  Is that error generated by one of the imported code files?  If you have a line number, can you show us the code?

Comment: The error mysteriously stopped occurring today after I completely reset my Unity project (created a new project and imported stuff back in)... Now my only issue is that `ROSBridgeLib` and its parts won't show up in my autocomplete in VS17, but the code seems to run without issue.